# Lighting Issue On Snapshots

Tags: gpio, pi-3, led

I'm creating a proof of concept project for my Pi 3. The concept is to take a photo using a USB webcam  when a button is pressed. That part was simple using OpenCV. However, the lighting is fairly poor where I'm testing this. So I'm trying to find a mobile solution for the lighting.

I need to be able to run the lighting with no power from outlets, etc. So either from the USB or it's own battery source, etc. And the second criteria is to be able to trigger the light using the Rasperry Pi.

I've had issues on finding something for this because I get a lot of how to tutorials on lighting up a single LED, etc.